# Missmatch between expected memory size of an dotnet application and real consumed memory under linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, dump

I would appreciate some help understanding the size of an memory dump.
Background: I have an net7 console application (main app) running in a container, which is hosted in Kubernetes with another net7 console application (sidecar).
The memory of the main app under a test scenario is `~570MB` and I get a full memory dump (using procdump for linux or dotnet dump). Based on the target environment I need to reduce the memory of the container and started to analyse what is in memory to learn what is consuming so much.

Size of all GC Heaps combined: 94MB
Size of Modules: 69,3MB
Native Heap Size: 51.8 MB
Embedded Resources (e.g. bitmaps): 0
Number of Threads: 49 (total), 20 (alive)

My rough size calculation is:
GCHeap (94) + 2* Modules (69,3) + Native Heap (51,8) + 1MB * Threads (49)  = `333,4MB`
(I doubled the size of the Modules, as approximation for the jitted assemblies)

--> The difference between the memory use I expected and what is really consumed is `~ 238MB (42%)`

What do I miss?
Can someone point me to any documentation/tool/etc. to understand where the unexpected memory is comming from?

I tried analysing the dump in dotMemory and dotnet dump but stuck, as the numbers I found looked good but the total memory consumed was so high.

Edit (1): Screenshot from dotMemory Heap Fragmentation:

[image: Screenshot from dotMemory Heap Fragmentation:]

Comment: Threads get (stack limit) of address space each, but the whole thread stack doesn't get committed, only as much as has been used.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks this would make the difference even bigger

Comment: > The memory of the main app under a test scenario is ~570MB
What type of memory is it? Virtual, private, resident, shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to answer my own question, and list my learnings:

(1) The core dump contains also native libraries used by dotnet, and those can have own memory pages allocated (own heaps). For my applications the following libraries were loaded:

| Name | Size [KiB] |
| --- | --- |
| /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.67.1 | 27748 |
| /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.67.1 | 3092 |
| /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 | 3008 |
| /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.67.1 | 1948 |
| /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so | 1856 |
| /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28 | 1832 |
| /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.31.so | 1296 |
| /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 | 588 |
| /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so | 172 |
| /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.31.so | 120 |
| /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 | 104 |
| /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.31.so | 96 |
| /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.31.so | 56 |
| /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.31.so | 40 |
| /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.31.so | 32 |
| /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.31.so | 24 |

(2) The default thread stack size is OS dependent under Debian linux, it is `8 MiB` This can be checked by running `ulimit -s` in the shell.

(3) Memory pages that are "allocated" will be stored in core dump (as long as they are not flagged with `Not Include in Core Dump` (dd) this is independent if they are loaded in physicall memory or not.

(4) The information which memory pages are allocated, isn't stored in the core dump itself. It can be retrieved via `cat /proc/<pid>/maps` or `cat /proc/<pid>/smaps` (smaps containing more details). Please read [proc man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for details.

(5) Memory pages, based on a file named `memfd:doublemapper (deleted)` are basically jit'ed code. It is called double mapper as the same memory page is mapped twice by dotnet one time as writable and secondly as executable to avoid security issues.

If the `memfd:doublemapper (deleted)` memory pages grow other time and the application don't use System.Emit to generate code at runtime, it can be that an delegate or anonymous function can't be cached by dotnet runtime and has to jit those code over and over again.

(6) If the smaps show anonymous memory pages, occupying unexpected memory. Those allocation need to be tracked down using native linux tooling.

As an first step it is important to load the debug symbols:

```bash
echo "install dotnet-symbol tool"
dotnet tool install dotnet-symbol --tool-path /tmp/tools
echo "use dotnet-symbol to get debug symbols of current dotnet version"
/tmp/tools/dotnet-symbol /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.??/*
echo "Add Package Server containign debug symbol packages"
echo "deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs) main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-updates main restricted universe multiverse | \
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-proposed main restricted universe multiverse" | \
tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list
echo "Install debug symbol packages"
apt install -y --no-install-recommends libc6-dbg libssl3-dbgsym openssl-dbgsym libicu67-dbgsym libstdc++6-dbgsym
```

The next step is to choose the right debugger, I would start with [heaptrack](https://github.com/KDE/heaptrack) or it this is not sufficient use [strace](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html).

```bash
echo "Run demo application under heaptrack"
heaptrack -o /mnt/diagnostics/heaptrack.$(echo $HOSTNAME)_$(date +%T).zst /usr/bin/dotnet /app/demo.dll
echo "Run demp application under strace, limit to memory releated system calls"
strace -k -f -e trace=mmap,munmap,mprotect -o /mnt/diagnostics/$(echo $HOSTNAME)_memory_trace_$(date +%T).txt /usr/bin/dotnet /app/demo.dll
```

The analysis of the heaptrack output can be done, via it's gui application or by using a command line tool: `heaptrack_print -l 1 -a 0 -T 0 -p 0 -f /mnt/diagnostics/heaptrack.MyHostName_12:00:00.zst`.

Answer (score 0):

Some memory may be reserved by managed heaps but not used due to heap fragmentation. Does the value "GCHeap 94MB" include the full heap size or only the size of allocated objects?
Could you please open this dump in dotMemory and attach a screenshot of `Inspections | Heap fragmentation` section?

Comment: It is the full size of the GCHeap, I've added the screenshot to the questions